# Presenting PNG screen comps

Tags: website-design

Just wondering if anyone has hammered out any good solutions to presenting PNG screen comps to clients, especially if there are more than a dozen screens. Adobe Bridge has some half decent HTML gallery output options, but I was wondering what other tools and techniques people use to remotely and reliably present full-quality comps.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Subfolio has been created for that purpose and it is free. http://www.subfolio.com

It is a file browser working with FTP, no CMS.

Comment: Examples: http://portfolio.area17.com/projects / http://studio.visualcurrent.com / http://juliabernard.net/PROJETS

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive is a nice, simple way to put together a presentation that you have control over. I've used this recently in conjunction with Google+ Hangouts to do the whole presentation: audio, video, and screen share. When the conference is over, you can share the presentation with the client (if you choose) and give them read-only access on your Drive account. Of course, you could do essentially the same thing with a PDF that you screen share from your desktop.

You could also search for CSS slide shows and build a site hosted on your domain using that format. It's just more work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This seems like a compelling technique, especially when it's crucial to control the pace.

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom php script which simply displays all images in any directory on a web server and places the file names below the image. This allows a web link to show the image and it's title without any additional effort on my part. It's all configured to display how I want it via a loop and I've styled it via CSS to match my site design.

I simply dump all the png, jpg, gif files I need the client to see in a folder on my web server, drop in the custom php script titled "index.php" and send the client the link to the directory on the web server.

I also have similar custom scripts to display a list of links for transferring .zip or .pdf files. In addition, to a hybrid page which will display images and download links at the same time.

Comment: Also a great option. There's no solution like a custom solution I suppose. Thanks.